# Problems with a reusable Click to Edit Directive on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, using-directives

I'm using the Reusable Click to Edit Directive from [Icelab](http://icelab.com.au/articles/levelling-up-with-angularjs-building-a-reusable-click-to-edit-directive/). I've used it successfully in several places in my app, but I run into problems when I try to edit elements that are inside other directives.

As the directives are calling the elements one by one, as in the following code:

```
<my-continent text='{{questions.n2A.answer.1.name}}' continent-id="1"></my-continent>
```

I don't see how can I implement the reusable directive in them, as it generates a general block of html code, not a specific one for each element called with the directive my continent.

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYbtFYvKo3Y4SXAud5mA?p=preview) where the problem is visible.

If I add the click-to-edit directive into my-continent, it breakes. You can see what I mean on line 47 of the html, when I add click-to-edit="questions.n2A.answer.1.name" onto the line as shown under.

```
 <my-continent text='{{questions.n2A.answer.1.name}}' continent-id="1" click-to-edit="questions.n2A.answer.1.name"></my-continent>
```

Any idea about what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used your plunker to check your problem and the moment I added click-to-edit to myContinent I've got an error in console linking to this:

[Error on AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/multidir?p0=clickToEdit&p1=myContinent&p2=template&p3=%3Cdiv%20class=%22click-to-edit%22%20text=%22%7B%7Bquestions.n2A.answer.1.name%7D%7D%22%20continent-id=%221%22%20click-to-edit=%22%22%3E)

So basicly your code is not working because you create new scope in both directives. Hope that helps